# Dealing with impure side-effects in FP, IO Monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

Trying to understand how best deal with side-effects in FP.

I implemented this rudimentary IO implementation:

```
  trait IO[A] {
    def run: A
  }
  object IO {
    def unit[A](a: => A): IO[A] = new IO[A] { def run = a }
    def loadFile(fileResourcePath: String) = IO.unit[List[String]]{ 
        Source.fromResource(fileResourcePath).getLines.toList }
    def printMessage(message: String) = IO.unit[Unit]{ println(message) }
    def readLine(message:String) = IO.unit[String]{ StdIn.readLine() }
  }
```

I have the following use case:

```
- load lines from log file
- parse each line to BusinessType object
- process each BusinessType object
- print process result
```

Case 1:
So Scala code may look like this

```
val load: String => List[String]
val parse: List[String] => List[BusinessType]
val process: List[BusinessType] => String
val output: String => Unit
```

Case 2:
I decide to use IO above:

```
val load: String => IO[List[String]]
val parse: IO[List[String]] => List[BusinessType]
val process: List[BusinessType] => IO[Unit]
val output: IO[Unit] => Unit
```

In case 1 the load is impure because it's reading from file so is the output is also impure because, it's writing the result to console.

To be more functional I use case 2.

Questions:

```
- Aren't case 1 and 2 really the same thing?
- In case 2 aren't we just delaying the inevitable? 
  as the parse function will need to call the io.run 
  method and cause a side-effect?
- when they say "leave side-effects until the end of the world" 
  how does this apply to the example above? where is the 
  end of the world here?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your IO monad seems to lack all the monad stuff, namely the part where you can `flatMap` over it to build bigger IO out of smaller IO. That way, everything stays "pure" until the call `run` at the very end.

> In case 2 aren't we just delaying the inevitable? 
>     as the parse function will need call the io.run 
>     method and cause a side effect?

No. The `parse` function should not call `io.run`. It should return another IO that you can then combine with its input IO.

> when they say "leave side-effects until the end of the world" 
>     how does this apply to the example above? where is the 
>     end of the world here?

End of the world would be the last thing your program does. You only `run` once. The rest of your program "purely" builds one giant IO for that.

Something like

```
def load(): IO[Seq[String]]    
def parse(data: Seq[String]): IO[Parsed]  // returns IO, because has side-effects
def pureComputation(data: Parsed): Result  // no side-effects, no need to use I/O
def output(data: Result): IO[Unit]

// combining effects is "pure", so the whole thing
// can be a `val` (or a `def` if it takes some input params)
val program: IO[Unit] = for {
      data <- load()    // use <- to "map" over IO
      parsed <- parse()
      result = pureComputation(parsed)  // = instead of <-, no I/O here 
      _ <- output(result)
   } yield ()

// only `run` at the end produces any effects
def main() {
   program.run()
}
```

Comment: so would "val parse: IO[List[String]] => List[BusinessType]" look like this then "val parse: IO[List[String]] => IO[List[BusinessType]]"?

Comment: No, it would be `def parse(in: List[String]): IO[List[BusinessType]]`. `IO` appears only on the result side (if at all, if there is no side-effect, it can just be `List[BusinessType]`. So how do you get the input out of the IO that produced it in the step before? You `flatMap`:  `stepOne.flatMap( in: List[String] => parse(in))`. The `flatMap` "unwraps" the data for you.